# Add buttons and texts in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

Hi friends i want to create a view in that I can add texts and buttons to. And I want to       maintain the sequence. Like in a text view i want to add texts then buttons then again texts.
And also want to edit in same area.
I can add buttons in `UITextview` but how do I maintain the sequence of text that i added after button and before any button ?
Is there any sample code for it ?

I am adding buttons in UITextView by

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton .frame = CGRectMake(100, myTextView.contentSize.height, 90, 30);
[myButton setTitle:@"button text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myTextView addSubview:myButton ];
```

but i can not able to move cursor after this button.

Comment: Are you trying to layout the text so that the button(s) are inline with the text, i.e. embedded with the flow of text?  If so, it may be possible with CoreText, but I'm unaware of any existing solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not add UILabel and UITextField controls in the same manner, using contentSize.height each time?

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you mean by 'texts' here - if you're not talking about a text or label control, are you trying to say that you want to stick buttons in the middle of a text view and have the text displayed in the textview flow around it (before and after it)?

Comment: I would strongly discourage this as it defies expected behaviour for that type of control. Consider having a text view, then a button, then a text view all sitting one above the other in a container of some sort (i.e., children of larger view). That way each control behaves as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Create a uiview subclass for the parent of the text view and override hit test sort of like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  // Check if the touch occurs within a rect or below a certain point
  BOOL isInsidePassThroughArea = point.y + self.textView.contentOffset.y < 72.f;
  if (isInsidePassThroughArea) {
    return [self.contentView hitTest:point withEvent:event];
  }

  return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```